# error: used struct type value where scalar is required for(;*ptr;ptr++)

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, structure, scalar-subquery

Can you please explain the reason behind this error.

**Error code:**

> used struct type value where scalar is required   `for(;*ptr;ptr++)`"for the below code?

Are there any reason why we aren't allowed struct variables in for loop?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct student
{
        char name[20]; // Given
        int math;  // Marks in math (Given)
        int phy;   // Marks in Physics (Given)
        int che;   // Marks in Chemistry (Given)
        int total; // Total marks (To be filled)
        int rank;  // Rank of student (To be filled)
};

static int count=1;
void enter_data(struct student* arr,int num);
void print_data(struct student* arr,int num);
int main()
{
        int num=1;
        char ch;
        printf("Enter the number of student records you want to input?..\n");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        struct student *arr=(struct student*)malloc(num*sizeof(struct student));



        printf("Do you want to enter the student record...(Y/N)\n");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
        {
                enter_data(arr,num);
                printf("The created record is .....\n");
                print_data(arr,num);

        }
        else
                return 0;


}

void enter_data(struct student* arr,int num)
{
        int i;
        struct student* ptr=arr;
        for(;count<=num;ptr++,count++)
        {
                printf("Enter the name of the candidate...\n");
                scanf("%s",ptr->name);
                printf("Enter the marks scored in maths,phy,che....\n");
                scanf("%d%d%d",&ptr->math,&ptr->phy,&ptr->che);
                ((ptr->total)=(ptr->math)+(ptr->phy)+(ptr->che));

        }
}

void print_data(struct student* arr,int num)
{
        int i;
        struct student* ptr=arr;
        for(;*ptr!=NULL;ptr++)//error here
        {
                printf("Name of the candidate...%s\n",ptr->name);
                printf("Enter the marks scored in maths...%d\t physics... %d\tche... %d\n total=%d\n",ptr->math,ptr->phy,ptr->che,ptr->total);

        }
}
```

Comment: The error is on `*ptr!=NULL` . I.e. you're comparing a `struct student` to `NULL`. That dereference shouldn't be there. I would think the reported error message, "Invalid operands to binary expression ('struct student' and 'void *')" would have made that obvious. And fyi, even after fixing that I don't think that's the result you want. You need a counter in that loop.

Comment: Actually, you need to use `num` and not `ptr` to terminate that loop.

Comment: I concur with @aschepler. That loop could be more like `for (; num--; ++ptr)` or similar. The value of `ptr` really doesn't belong in the conditional.

Comment: while checking the condition part i should not use struct variables?Is it by default or only in this condition?@aschepler@WhozCraig ?

Comment: Is there a shortcut to enter the previous inputs to the structure program a.out ,so that i can avoid giving the input again and again to the a.out file..@aschepler@WhozCraig

Comment: "*so that i can avoid giving the input again and again*" pipe it to `a.out` by doing `a.out <input.txt` with `input.txt` being a text file, with one line per each item you else enter by hand end finishing input by hitting the ENTER-key. Mind to end the last line with a new line, so you in fact have an empty line at the end of `input.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Increment  the pointer that reference's the values at particular address not the value at the address of that pointer. `*ptr!=NULL` means you are comparing struct student to `NULL`

```
 for(;ptr!=NULL;ptr++)//error fixed here
            {
                    printf("Name of the candidate...%s\n",ptr->name);
                    printf("Enter the marks scored in maths...%d\t physics... %d\tche... %d\n total=%d\n",ptr->math,ptr->phy,ptr->che,ptr->total);

            }
```

Comment: This indeed fixes the compiler error. However, when do you expect `ptr` to obtain a value of `NULL` , and thus break the loop? It is walking an *array* sequence The actual fix is to iterate at-most `num` times, incrementing `ptr` with each iteration.